# Rebasing a master branch onto a feature branch, getting conflicts again after rebase

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a feature branch which was taken from master some time ago.  Now I want to rebase master onto that feature branch, so I did this command:

```
git rebase master
```

Then I continued in SourceTree because I got conflicts.  I resolved them one by one, then continued rebasing, this went on for some time.  Finally very happy everything seemed done.

This is what Sourcetree now shows me:

[image]

When I run

```
git rebase master
```

I get

```
Current branch 2FA is up to date.Current branch 2FA is up to date.
```

When I do:

```
git pull
```

I get a list of files I have to redo again.

```
Auto-merging db/schema.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in db/schema.rb
Auto-merging config/locales/nl.yml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in config/locales/nl.yml
Auto-merging app/views/users/_form.html.haml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/views/users/_form.html.haml
Auto-merging app/models/user.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/models/user.rb
Auto-merging app/models/permission.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/models/permission.rb
Auto-merging app/helpers/application_helper.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/helpers/application_helper.rb
Auto-merging app/controllers/users_controller.rb
CONFLICT (modify/delete): app/controllers/companies_controller.rb deleted in HEAD and modified in 1110e1f18d4ab388eab767509d95be10b9953a36. Version 1110e1f18d4ab388eab767509d95be10b9953a36 of app/controllers/companies_controller.rb left in tree.
Auto-merging app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.sass
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.sass
Auto-merging app/assets/stylesheets/backapp.css
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/assets/stylesheets/backapp.css
Auto-merging Gemfile.lock
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Gemfile.lock
Auto-merging Gemfile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Gemfile
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Why is this?  I already did the work of figuring that out.  This way rebasing seems a lot more work than just merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rebased your feature branch on `master`, you rewrote the history of that branch.  What actually happened is that you replayed your work on top of the `master` branch.  Once you completed the rebase, the normal thing to do would have been to force push your feature branch to the remote:

```
git push --force origin feature
```

What happened when you did a `git pull` is that you told Git to bring in the current remote `feature` branch, presumably via the merge strategy.  Since you had just rewritten your `feature` branch, Git treated the remote branch as "new," at least with regard to that a merge should even take place.  In any case, doing `git pull` was incorrect, and all you probably needed was to force push your feature branch.

If you are wondering why you would even want to use rebase over merge, it turns out that rebase has the ability to maintain a linear history in a feature branch.  This can be advantageous because it makes the history of a branch easy to read.  The downside is that everyone using this branch may need to do more work via rebasing.

Comment: Great!  I did git merge --abort to cancel the git pull.  After that I did git push --force origin 2FA  which didn't give any problems.  Thanks.